# Need to download files from a network drive in an mvc asp.net core intranet project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, intranet

I am a relatively new Asp.Net Core programmer.

I have a project for an intranet web application  (will not be visible to the outside world).

The application will reside on it's own webserver but users will need to download files from a network drive folder and it's subfolders . The network drive is mapped to the server.

I have managed to build a page and populate it with the network folders contents. However I'm struggling finding the means to download the files when the users select them.  In an effort to "Keep it simple" I did this in the view ...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Folder Explorer";
}

<h3>1 @Model.FolderName</h3>
<h4>2 @Model.URL</h4>
<h4>3 @Model.ParentFolderName</h4>
<ul>
    @*Listing the files *@
    @foreach (FolderExplorer.Models.FileModel file in Model.FileModelList)
    {
<li>
    
        <a href="\\popdata01\data\SomePath\SomeUser\SomeCase\SomeDoc.docx"  target="_blank" download> 
           download @(file.FileName)</a>
        . . . . . . @file.FileSizeText
        . . . . . . @file.FileSizeText
        . . . . . . @file.FileAccessed
    
</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This a simplistic version of what I'm trying - I can build my list of files in the view just fine, but  the only set of curcumstances where this code actually works both in Visual Studio and when deployed on the server is with Internet Explorer - nothing else.

My problem is thus ...

My app is on server  http://mywebserver ( for discussion) but the data the users need to select from is on //popdata01/data/ - a separate server. In Asp.Net Core -how do I successfully download files from a network folder external to the actual project/app?

Again this is for an intranet only and specific subset of users.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `http://mywebserver` will be _serving_ files from `\\popdata01\data` or _linking to_ files from `\\popdata01\data` (or even `http://popdata01/data`)?  Everything suggests the former but then near the end you mention connecting to `http://popdata01/data/`, so HTTP instead of SMB.  In any case, if `mywebserver` will be itself accessing files on `\\popdata01` — either just to list them or to read and serve them, too — then the web server process will either need to run as or connect as a user with access to `\\popdata01`.  Internet Explorer might only work because it's doing NTLM authentication.

Comment: it is actually a network folder visible on the webserver....

Comment: Is the issue that the code doesn't produce a directory listing, or the page appears correctly in the browser but clicking the link does something other than open/download the file?  You don't say what other browser(s) you might be using, but by default (on Win10/IE11, at least) Internet Explorer will automatically use the user's Windows credentials for sites in the `Intranet` zone (see `Internet options` → `Security` tab → `Local intranet` → `Custom level...` → `User Authentication` → `Logon`), whereas other browsers would need to be configured to do so, if they even support it at all.

Comment: I am able to build a page that lists all my files, however when I try to download the file using the spoofed  <a href="\\popdata01\data\SomePath\SomeUser\SomeCase\SomeDoc.docx"  target="_blank" download> 
           download @(file.FileName)</a> as an example (hardcoded for simplicity - a file and location on the network folder) .. It will always work with Internet explorer - i.e. download the file from the network location, the other browsers fail to download for various reasons. . Most of my users prefer chrome and our shop may be moving to edge in the future so I need a more 'global' fix

Comment: i've tried, chrome. firefox, internet explorer and edge...

Comment: Depending on what those "various reasons" are, it sounds like authentication is indeed the issue here. Using your current code, you'll need to investigate enabling Windows authentication for those browsers; if you're using Active Directory there may be Group Policy templates to handle that. Otherwise, you'll need `mywebserver` to not only list the directory but serve the files from it, too; this will have the consequence of all clients getting the same file permissions: those of the account ASP.NET is running/connected as. This is all just the pitfall of having a web browser consume UNC paths.